# Is there any advantage installing modules like socket.io/express globally?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, npm

And if so, I'm interested in knowing if there is any way to run them from `/usr/local/lib` folder instead of installing those modules in each project's folder I'm working on.

Comment: The downside to having Express installed globally is that if you upgrade your Express to a newer version (perhaps even a version that some some incompatibilities with earlier versions), then you have to upgrade all your apps at once to work with the new version of Express.  If you install Express individually for each project, then you only have to deal with a new version of Express for a given app when you choose to actually upgrade that particular app.  With disk space so inexpensive, I see no reason to install much of anything globally.

Comment: My main concern was about the space it can take supposing I'm going to make many different projects, since every node_modules it takes about 2MB minimum

Comment: So, if you have 100 node.js projects, it costs you 200MB of disk space.  That's nothing these days to have the flexibility of independently upgrading a node.js project.

Comment: I see... In the worst case I just need to remove the node_modules folder and reinstall the modules through the package.json anyway. Thank you all for the answers, very appreciate it, it's my first time actually asking something on Stackoverflow. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node documentation says that installing global modules should be relegated to those that require command line access ( such as nodemon etc.. ).

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

> **Which to choose**
>
> Just like how global variables are kind of gross, but also necessary
> in some cases, global packages are important, but best avoided if not
> needed.
>
> In general, the rule of thumb is:
>
> If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program,
> using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of
> your project.
>
> If you’re installing something that you want to use in
> your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so
> that its binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.

The only other related issue I can think of to your question is that you can install *express generator* globally as it allows you to create an instance of their web scaffolding.

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

But that is different and not the same thing as installing express itself globally.

So as far as I can tell the answer is no - their is no benefit to this.

Comment: I personally don't even like installing command line modules globally unless they are really tools like `node-static` that I might use outside a node.js project. If it's a project dependency it should be in the `package.json` and usable from the command line like `"$(npm bin)"/gulp`, with global installation an option for convenience, but never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well, personally, no. I ended up messing up my repos trying to globally install express and other modules. I really can't see the benefit of sparing a few extra seconds when you know it can't mess up your system :D And just to add, don't try globally installing mongoDB, REALLY ended up badly.